# jQuery select not working in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery select which works in most browsers axcept IE. The code is as follows;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function parseCatSelect()
        {
            $('#d_cat select:empty').parent().html('<p><span class="placeholder">No categories available</span></p>');
            $('#d_cat select').attr('name', 'e');
        }

        function loadCategories()
        {
            $('#d_cat').html('<p><span class="placeholder">Please wait&hellip;</span></p>').load('/brand_categories.asp', {label: $('#d_brand select option:selected').val()}, parseCatSelect);
        }

    $('#d_brand').load(
        '/brands.asp',
        function() {
            $('#d_brand select').attr('name', 'd').live('change', loadCategories).trigger('change');
        }
    );

</script>
```

Could anyone help with a solution for this issue please? You can see this live (in FireFox) at www.wearecapital.com

Thank you.

Comment: Which bit isn't working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd change this:

```
.live('change', loadCategories)
```

To this:

```
.change(loadCategories)
```

You're rebinding after the ajax load anyway, so `.live()` isn't giving you much here...and I've had plenty of problems in corner cases, `change` still doesn't bubble completely correctly in IE.

By default it doesn't bubble at all, jQuery is doing some magic here to bubble the event, but it's not perfect yet.  Also note that it didn't bubble **at all** in IE (even via jQuery) until **1.4+**, you're on **1.3.2** looking at the page, so `.live()` wouldn't work with `change` in IE at all.

Comment: nice info to know about bubbling in IE

Comment: The selects are working now, but nothing happens when you click on the 'Go' button in IE7. IE8 seems fine.

Comment: @Neil - Change this: `<button id="b_submit" class="button right">Go</button>` to this: `<button id="b_submit" type="submit" class="button right">Go</button>`